# How to calculate the number of characters(spaces are excluded) within a pair of tags in JQuery or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spaces

How to calculate the characters(spaces are excluded) within a pair of tags in JQuery or Javascript? What function?

For example:

```
<pre id="mytext">This is the text.      This is the text.</pre>
```

How to know how many characters or words in $("#mytext")?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
var chars = $('#mytext').text().replace(/ /g, '').length;
```

If you want to exclude *any* whitespace, not just spaces:

```
var chars = $('#mytext').text().replace(/\s/g, '').length;
```